# jquery append not showing in safari

Tags: ajax, jquery, dom, safari

I have a working progress bar inside a Django app. Except in Safari the bar shows up only under weird circumstances.

First, I have the progress bar appended via jquery/ajax combination:

```
var $progress = $('<div id="upload-progress" class="upload-progress"></div>')
.appendTo($('#webfileuploadform'))
.append('
    <div class="progress-container">
        <div class="progress-info">uploading 0%</div>
        <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    </div>');

//This is all one string, I've just broken it up like this so it's readable.

//Called on form submit
$.ajax({
    ...yada yada...
    success: function(data){
        $progress.show(); <-- shows the div(s)
        ...more yada...
```

In Firefox and Chrome, this all works fine. In Safari, this is actually working as well, just not displaying. When I open up Safari developer tools and drill down to the `<form>` I can see that the DOM elements are being appended to the form as they should. The width of the progress bar and the text of the progress-info div are updating correctly as well (in developer tools). The problem is the `#upload-progress` div is not showing in the browser even though I see it exists in the developer tools!

What blows my mind is that if I click the grey 'x' in Safari to force stop the page, the progress bar then shows up!

Another weird thing is that once I click the form submit, if I highlight any dom element in my developer tools the entire page is blanked out with the same color I have on a wrapper div around the entire page! Also, if I highlight an element in the developer tools before I click the submit button, then click, the page just jumps straight to blanking out again. I don't even have to move around in the developer tools.

Very strange behavior. I have no idea what's going on...

I've read some things saying safari doesn't redraw the DOM when css is applied with jquery? I don't think that's true, but does this have something to do with it?

### UPDATE

So this problem persists even outside the ajax function, but works outside the submit handler. That is:

**problem persists when I click the submit button (no ajax code here)**

```
$('#webfileuploadform').submit(function(){
    $('#webfileuploadform').append('<div id="upload-progress" class="upload-progress">asdf</div>');
    $('#upload-progress').append('<div class="progress-container"><div class="progress-info">uploading 0%</div><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>');
    ...
});
```

**same code outside of the submit handler works**

```
$('#webfileuploadform').append('<div id="upload-progress" class="upload-progress">asdf</div>');
$('#upload-progress').append('<div class="progress-container"><div class="progress-info">uploading 0%</div><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>');
$('#webfileuploadform').submit(function(){
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with webkit. The [bug report is here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23933). Webkit cannot handle XMLHttpRequests after a form submit. A workaround that I used was to submit the form to a target iframe. Turns out the bug only happens when the target is the same `document` that the `form` is in...

Changed target:

```
<form action="my_django_view" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formID" target="theIframeName">
    ...
</form>
```

Hidden iframe on page:

```
<iframe name="theIFrameName" id="style-me-with-display-none"></iframe>
```

Although it should be noted I'm working with legacy code here, which is why I'm handling file objects with forms. If you are starting from scratch, there are better ways to handle file objects nowadays and this method should be avoided.